# Moving a small pin up and down using <12v

Tags: arduino, electromagnetism, power-electronics

Hobbyist here. I'd like to move a pin up and down using <12v. How can I do that.

I don't wanna do it the mechanical way as I have three of them. my first option is using a servo in vertical way and making it moving up and down.

**UPDATE**

The size of the pin is 2-1CM, I want to use arduino to connect it and manage it.

[image]

Comment: How far do you want to move it?  And how fast (or slow)?

Comment: Several other considerations - do you need to know where the pin is? How accurate does that need to be? Do they need to move in unison, or independently? What is providing the voltage?

Comment: @PeterBennett THanks for your answer! it's 1-2 CM pin, I want to move it like 1-1.5CM. The speed is not very essential, as long as I move the three of them together (3 together, or 2 together, based on the scenario )

Comment: @SeanBoddy I'am thinking of a way to use the small motor pin, somehow to make it go up and down. I am looking for a starting point to look on internet and learn how to do it. Where can I start ?

Comment: The speed probably matters more than you think. The reason Peter asked that is because, on the face of it, this is probably best handled by a magnetic coil, which will move quite fast. If you need verification of the position, then a motorized setup will work best. Since it sounds conditional, you'll need three separate units. Is it important for them to be completely synchronized? It's also going to be important to know what these pins are doing; it sounds like you need them to interface with something. We can help you a lot, but first we need to help you ask the relevant questions.

Comment: @SeanBoddy Thanks! - I am interfacing it with Arduino. I need to think of the circuit. Imagine it as conditional system, all the possible permutations are (000, 001, 010, .. 111), where 0 for OFF, 1 for 0N, and every position of the digit related to one of the three pins (eg: 111 all the three pins are on. 101, the first and the third pins are ON while second is OFF). I can send the pulse from arduino (that's something I can do), now, I need to know if the magnetic coil is what I need to work on, and how can I modify a motor so I can make it work on this scenario ? thanks again for ur time.

Comment: @SeanBoddy When I said that speed is not important, I didn't mean to neglict it, but it's not critical issue in the scenario I told u about.

Answer (score 1):

For higher speed output, you'll need solenoids. These are readily available commercially. You'll need to specify length of stroke, holding force, and push or pull, among other things. You are also probably going to need an alternate source of power and a relay setup to control them adequately.

For slower speeds, a servo mechanism may be best - simply attach the pin to a small gear with a pivoting arm such that a 180 degree causes the desired extension. I say simply - this could actually be pretty difficult to do with simple hand tools.

Depending on the specific application, you may also want to look at other electromechanical or mechanical options, such as pneumatics, or even hydraulics - everything depends on the application.

Comment: Thanks! The second option seems raisonable, but powering 3 servos might be a problelm. I will check and get back to you.